# How to display an image from URLRequest twice (downloading it only once)?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, bitmapdata

I am just wondering, if it is possible to load an image via URLRequest once, and display that image twice? Or do i have to load the image 2 times?

Edit:
Also want to ask if it is possible to duplicate the bitmaps when they are loaded in a loop(array).

For example:

```
var duplicate:Array = new Array(loadedArray.push(e.target.content));
```

When i am trying the code :

```
        loadedArray.push(e.target.content);

        var duplicate:Array = new Array(loadedArray.push(e.target.content));
```

It doesnt give me any errors, but from before it adds the bitmap with no problem, but now, it doesnt add anything.

And when i tried

```
var duplicate:Array = new Array(loadedArray as Bitmap);
addChild(duplicate[0]);
```

I have an error Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.

Comment: Guys stop messing around with the title! It's about **duplicating** an image, it's not important how many times it's downloaded.. Keep in mind that we need to help other people finding the solutions. Sometimes they will need to duplicate **without** loading anything!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duplicating Bitmap or BitmapData is easy. There are a lot of options, these are few of them:

```
// in your case, but can be any Bitmap
var original:Bitmap = Bitmap(loader.content);

// we actually need the bitmapData; separate for easy reading
var originalBitmapData:BitmapData = original.bitmapData;

var duplicate:Bitmap = new Bitmap(originalBitmapData);

// this one returns brand new copy of the BitmapData (sometimes needed)
var duplicate:Bitmap = new Bitmap(originalBitmapData.clone());
```

`copyPixels()` on BitmapData is also super fast and can be used for duplication, depending if there is already Bitmap(Data) instantiated.

Comment: sweet, i will give it a try, thanks! But when i do removeChild, it is possible to remove just 1 right? i dont have to remove both Child at the same time?

Comment: @Clarklight After you do `new Bitmap(...)` these two are separate items, so yes, you can manipulate them separately. On a side note, once you load a bitmap, you should store its `bitmapData` object elsewhere to be able to quickly reference it, without any `loader` objects.

Comment: @Vesper Thanks, i will give it a go, because mine at the moment is loaded thru an Array, i did loadedArray.push(e.target.content); So i am just wondering how to duplicate the whole array, then i can add a specific image from that array.

Comment: Hi I just added 1 more part for the question, it is still about adding a duplicate bitmap but duplicating the whole array of Bitmap. I tried to do it,but it doesn't add anything, i believe because the content has moved to the duplicate from loadedArray.